# Casting and validating Ecto custom type

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm writing a custom [`Ecto.Type`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html) for colors (serialized and parsed as CSS colors).

The behaviour specifies that the [`cast/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html#c:cast/1) callback should return `:error` unless successful. It does not allow for returning an error reason, and will generate the generic *"is invalid"* error description when used with a Changeset.

What is the best way to allow better error messages on in changesets on invalid (uncasteable) input? I would like to create a `validate_color` function to be used on changesets, but if the cast failed the field will already have the generic error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible as of Ecto v3.0.0:

> When returning `{:error, keyword()}`, the returned keyword list will be preserved in the changeset errors, similar to `Changeset.add_error/4`. Passing a `:message` key, will override the default message.

[link to docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html#c:cast/1)